# Replace count 0 with 'N/A' in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I my following query, the last column returns the count of the instances, for this instances with 0 count I would like to replace them with 'N/A'?

This query does not seems to work

```
select m.id, m.desc, count(IF(i.id is NULL,'N/A',i.id)) as quant
from menu m left join items i
on m.id = i.id
group by m.id
order by m.id;
```

The above query outputs as

```
============================
m.id     |c.desc     | qaunt
============================
1234     | Shoes     | 1
1235     | Socks     | 2
1236     | Clothes   | 0
===========================
```

Expected result:

```
============================
m.id     |m.desc     | qaunt
============================
1234     | Shoes     | 1
1235     | Socks     | 2
1236     | Clothes   | N/A
===========================
```

Could you please suggest me the changes in the above query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is tested) Your query is counting the results of the if, and I think you want the inverse. I am using a pairing of IFNULL and NULLIF, which together say "if the count is zero, translate that to NULL. Then if it's NULL, use "N/A" for this column.

```
select m.id, m.desc, 
IFNULL(NULLIF(count(i.id), 0), "N/A") as quant
from menu m left join items i
on m.id = i.id
group by m.id
order by m.id;
```

To be pedantic for mysql, you can ensure that the column is always a string via cast():

```
IFNULL(NULLIF(CAST(count(i.id) AS char), "0"), "N/A") as quant
```

This has the benefit of only counting once and no subquery.

Comment: This gives me all the values as BLOB in quant column, would this be the issue with the data type?

Comment: Possibly. I tested with item.id being an int, and I'm on 5.5.28

Comment: I would experiment with wrapping CAST() around things there.

Comment: could you suggest, how it would be with CAST?

Answer (score 2):

can you try

```
select m.id, m.desc, if(count(i.id) = 0,'N/A',count(i.id))) as quant
from menu m left join items i
on m.id = i.id
group by m.id
order by m.id;
```

Comment: I am afraid, This also gives me all the values as BLOB in the last column, why would be that?

Answer (score 0):

NULL & 0 are not the same

```
select m.id, m.desc, count(IF(i.id = 0,'N/A',i.id)) as quant
from menu m left join items i
on m.id = i.id
group by m.id
order by m.id;
```

Comment: `count(IF(i.id = 0,'N/A',i.id))` -- this expression is just wrong

Comment: I was illustrating that Null & 0 are not the same. I did not check the query

Comment: zerkms is right. that expression does not work, it still gives me 0 instead of 'N/A'

Comment: @david strachan: to demonstrate they aren't the same the easiest way is `SELECT 0 != null` - that is. But rewriting a wrong query to even more wrong one is barely an answer

Comment: NULL & 0 are indeed different things, but sir, that seems a completely irrelevant point here, sorry. The OP's approach was incorrect but their attempt at least understandable, even logical in a way: they were trying to account for `0`s by checking if there wasn't a match, hence the NULL check. Seriously, what in particular does your change to `i.id = 0` aim at accomplishing?

Comment: From Question `count(IF(i.id is NULL,'N/A',i.id))` i.id isn't NULL it 0 or more

Answer (score 0):

FOR MSSQL or TSQL change **IFNULL** with **ISNULL** and double quotes **`"`** with single quote **`'`**.

```
select m.id, m.desc, 
ISNULL(NULLIF(count(i.id), 0),'N/A') as quant
from menu m left join items i
on m.id = i.id
group by m.id
order by m.id;
```